# selected row color not getting even after applying custom css in kendo grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular6, kendo-grid

Hi i am loading the kendo grid dynamically on bootstrap modal popup i am defining the class in .css file of that particular component in angular but still color is not getting applied still shows red color for selected rows which is by default.

following is the code for kendo grid

```
 <div class="row">
    <kendo-grid [data]="previewGridSource" [selectable]="selectableSettings" 
    [rowClass]="rowCallback" [kendoGridSelectBy]="selectedCallback"
              [selectedKeys]="mySelection">
    <kendo-grid-checkbox-column title="Select" width="70"></kendo-grid-checkbox- 
     column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="BookingDetailId" title="BookingDetailId" 
     width="40" hidden="hidden">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Hours" title="Hours" width="80">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Loading" title="Loading" width="100" 
    [format]="format">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="StartDate" title="Start Date" width="100" format=" 
    {0: dd-MM-yyyy}">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="EndDate" title="End Date" width="100" format="{0: 
    dd-MM-yyyy}">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Unconfirmed" title="Unconfirmed" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <!-- <kendo-grid-column title="Done" width="100" >
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxDone" checked>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column> -->
  </kendo-grid>

   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pl-0 pr-0">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <button class="cancelBtn" (click)="cancel()"><span class="glyphicon 
   glyphicon-remove-sign pr-5"></span>Cancel</button>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <!--button class="deleteBtn" (click)="save()"><span class="glyphicon 
       glyphicon-ok-sign pr-5"></span>Submit</button-->
       <button class="addBtn" (click)="save()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
    ok-sign pr-5"></span>Submit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

following is the code in css file

```
.k-grid .k-state-selected {
 background-color:lightgreen;
 }
```

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: Can you provide a runable example? (e.g. via [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) ) Off the top of my head I'd guess that the [style scope](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope) is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following css classes.

```
/*for selected row color*/
.k-grid td.k-state-selected, .k-grid tr.k-state-selected>td 
{
   background-color:lightgreen;
}

/*for hover row color*/
.k-grid tbody tr:hover, .k-grid tbody tr.k-state-hover
{
   background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Comment: i used this code still not working, don't know why its not getting applied

Comment: @user9287106  could you please share the code snippet of where you have placed the css classes